# Finding an Arabic string in an Arabic text file in Python

Tags: python, arabic

I have an Arabic text file, and I want to know the line where a certain string has appeared, so I write the following code using python programming language.

```
 line_position = 0
    with open('arwiki_corpus.txt', 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            line_position += 1
            if thelastline in line:
                print(line_position)
                print(line)
                break
```

Where ( thelastline ) is the string that I want to search for in the ( arwiki_corpus.txt ), which contains the following:

thelastline = ' كما شاع استخدام الرصاص في صناعة قنوات المجاري وفي الإنشاءات المدنية والصناعات العسكرية، خاصّةً مع سهولة سبكه والتعامل الحرفي معه، ومقاومته للتآكل؛ بالإضافة إلى سهولة الحصول عليه، ورخص ثمنه'

The problem is, the condition (  if thelastline in line ) never return true, even though I could find the string when I search for it manually in the text

I tested the same code by searching for an English string in an English text file, and it worked right, So I guess the problem is that I am searching for an Arabic string in an Arabic text file...

I tried to replace the condition with this one:

```
 if araby.strip_tatweel(araby.strip_tashkeel(thelastline)) in araby.strip_tatweel(araby.strip_tashkeel(line)):
```

which will make some cleaning for the text, but still not working..

How could I solve that?

Comment: What is the encoding of the file? The string thelastline is inputted directly in the python file? In what encoding?

Comment: @rolf82 the ( thelastline ) is the last line from another Arabic text file which has a utf-8 encoding, the string contains html code so I clean it form that using BeautifulSoup,  here is the code:
    `with open(input_file, "r") as file:
        lastline = (list(file)[-1])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(lastline, 'html.parser')
    thelastline = soup.get_text()`

Comment: maybe your lastline contains an end of line, can you try with `lastline = (list(file)[-1]).strip()` ?

Comment: @rolf82 Yup you're right, that's work! thank you